# Django возможна ли многопроцессорность

Tags: python, django, многопоточность

Есть Django проект. В нем создаются отдельные процессы, которые должны быть привязаны к юзеру и работать до тех пор, пока юзер его не остановит. Сам процесс еще и записывает данные в бд (PostgreSQL).

Возможно ли это?
С помощью чего это можно провернуть?

Comment: вот что то похоже на то, что Вам нужно - https://github.com/arteria/django-background-tasks

Comment: @KoVadim, да похоже, но на сколько я понял, там невозможно "привязать" таск к юзеру и (если я правильно понял) макс кол-во тасков = cpu_count(?)

Comment: а зачем привязывать. Они что, будут висеть и дергать постоянно базу на наличие новых записей?

Comment: @KoVadim, юзер может просматривать записи, которые добавил процесс. Процесс может работать и день и два и неделю, пока его не остановит юзер, к которому привязан данный процесс

Comment: и когда пользователей станет чуточку больше, база скажет "ой-ой". Поэтому, просто запускайте свои таски, которые проверят что то важное в таблице и выполнят нужные действия по расписанию. Раз в минут или 20 секунд.

Comment: @KoVadim, не скажет, сам проект не для широкой публики, а процесс создает новую запись в бд примерно раз в 5 минут

Comment: Вполне возможно, что нужно пересмотреть архитектуру и все станет на свои места.